# EF Core 2 throws exception on SaveChanges, after first update for related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I ran in to a problem with editing/updating entries in db which has related entities. I am able to edit any entry once, and after that I am not able to update any dependent entity which has the same principal entity, as the entity I already modified

I have spent last 5 days or so, trying to solve this. all the advice that I have found on the net, did not work.

you can see the project @: https://github.com/nedimbih/WorkNotes

problematic part is this:

```
public partial class Work
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    

    public virtual Worker Worker { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartingTime { get; set; }
    public float Duration { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Worker : IdentityUser
{

    public Worker() => WorksDoneByWorker = new HashSet<Work>();

  
    public virtual  ICollection<Work> WorksDoneByWorker { get; set; }
}
```

In WorkRepository.cs I have this code

```
 internal int Update(Work input)
    {

        Work workInDb = _context.WorkList
                                .Include(w => w.Worker)
                                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == input.Id);

        if (workInDb != null)
        // v.1
        // {workInDb = input;}
        // v.2
        {
            workInDb.Note = input.Note;
            workInDb.StartingTime = input.StartingTime;
            workInDb.Duration = input.Duration;
            workInDb.Date = input.Date;
            workInDb.Worker = input.Worker;
        }
        int savedEntries;
        try
        {
            savedEntries = _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            savedEntries = 0;
            // used as a flag. Calling code acts upon it
        }
        return savedEntries;
    }
```

I can make updates on work entries only once, for a given worker.
after I edit/update one work entry (savedEntries holds value 2), I can no longer update any entry with same worker as updated entry. I get exception on SaveChanges saying that Worker with same id is already being tracked.
if I turn of line workInDb.Worker=input.Worker then it saves, but that is not functionality that I need.
if I turn on v.1 code instead of v.2 I get no exception but SaveChanges does nothing.
count of modified entries (in context) is 0 in both cases.

Comment: Don't you have to do _context.Add(workInDb); before you do SaveChanges ?

Comment: Not really. He's doing an update in the same context, so SaveChanges will "be enough" to persist the changes.

Comment: i have tried that earlier, but regardless of what i have used Add, Update, Entry, Attach it was throwing an exception on those methods, before SaveChanges. Without those it throws on SaveChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your model is right.
Try this:

```
public partial class Work
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

public int WorkerId { get; set; }
public Worker Worker { get; set; }

public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public TimeSpan StartingTime { get; set; }
public float Duration { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

and the instead of setting the worker set its Id like this:

```
 workInDb.WorkerId = input.Worker.Id;
```

This will prevent EF of trying to create and store a new Worker with the same Id, but instead in adding a relation to the existing worker.

Comment: i have tried this with string, not int, because Worker derives from UserIdentity. now it trows an exceptio saying "The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_WorkList_Worker_WorkerId\". The conflict occurred in database \"WorkRecords\", table \"dbo.Worker\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."  before this change i was able to do one update, now it throwes error at first update request

Comment: Did you make sure that the Worker.Id that you are setting on the Work is actually the right value? That error can happen when there is no Worker with that Id in the database.

Comment: that was it. many thanks bro :) i had a different db where i stored signed up users and another db for app data. i was importing workerid from users db and then writing it in worker table in app data db. muchas gracias :)